# How to sum total value of any foreach loop result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show Total Salary, which is the sum of all employee's net salary. How can I do that?  I have tried some code but its not working
[image: Please check this image]

```
            <tbody>
                <?php 

                $salary = 0;
                if (!empty($emp_salary_info)):foreach ($emp_salary_info as $v_emp_salary):

                $salary = $salary + $v_emp_salary->basic_salary;
                 ?>                    
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $v_emp_salary->employment_id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $v_emp_salary->first_name . ' ' . $v_emp_salary->last_name ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $gross = $v_emp_salary->basic_salary + $v_emp_salary->house_rent_allowance + $v_emp_salary->medical_allowance + $v_emp_salary->special_allowance + $v_emp_salary->fuel_allowance + $v_emp_salary->phone_bill_allowance + $v_emp_salary->other_allowance ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $deduction = $v_emp_salary->tax_deduction + $v_emp_salary->provident_fund + $v_emp_salary->other_deduction ?></td>
                            <?php $net_salary = $gross - $deduction ?>

                            <td><?php echo $net_salary ?></td>
                            <td><?php
                                if ($v_emp_salary->employment_type == 1) {
                                    echo 'Provision';
                                } else {
                                    echo 'Permanent';
                                }
                                ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo btn_view('admin/payroll/view_salary_details/' . $v_emp_salary->employee_id); ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo btn_edit('admin/payroll/manage_salary_details/' . $v_emp_salary->employee_id . '/' . $v_emp_salary->designations_id); ?>                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>                
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tbody>
```

this is code I have tried for sum the net salary

```
<?php           
    $salary = 0;
    if (!empty($emp_salary_info)):foreach ($emp_salary_info as $v_emp_salary):
        $salary = $salary + $v_emp_salary->basic_salary;

        echo 'Total Salary :' 
?> 
<?php echo $salary; ?>
```

Comment: *I have tried some code but its not working * - what's a code? what does it mean "not working" ?

Comment: put code into your question

Comment: You're adding to the `$salary` variable - but then where are you displaying it? __Please define 'not working'__

Comment: <?php echo 'Total Salary :' ?> <?php echo $salary; ?>

Comment: And whats the result of that echo?

Comment: as you can see in image JUTS NOTHING

Comment: Is it passing the `!empty($emp_salary_info)` condition? Write out your if and foreach in long hand (with opening and closing braces). Debug and check that the foreach is even looped through.

Comment: yeah its passing '!empty($emp_salary_info)'

Comment: help please......

Comment: If it is showing 0 then can you please put $v_emp_salary->basic_salary in one of the td for testing purpose. I think it did not have a value

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using data-tables for displaying table records. Try to print Total after completing record calculations.

In image you are displaying total before completing process.

Also change few lines of code

```
    if(!isset($v_emp_salary->basic_salary) || empty($v_emp_salary->basic_salary) || !is_numeric($v_emp_salary->basic_salary))
    {
        $v_emp_salary->basic_salary = 0;
    }

$salary = $salary + $v_emp_salary->basic_salary;
```

Still if you do not find total try to check data inside `$emp_salary_info` it may have empty or wrong data with salary.

Comment: Datatables normally don't need records to be printed in blade template. Instead it populates records. Please let me know if there are any scope or possibility in vegetables to print records

Comment: this code worked but it add last salary two time : emply one salary 11000 emply twp salary 10000 and it show total salary = 31000 not 21000